# Cannot image Acer Iconia W510 with custom Windows 10 image

Tags: windows-10, windows-8, images

I am trying to image Acer Iconia W510 machines with a Windows 10 image we made. We have already successfully imaged a few dozen. About ten, however, refuse to take the image. They are currently on Windows 8. The image in on an external hard drive that we plug into the USB port.

The steps I take for the imaging process are as follows: "Change PC Settings"->"Update and recovery"->"Recovery"->"Advanced startup" And I click on the "Restart now" button, which sends me to a screen with three options, Continue to windows 8.1, Troubleshoot, and turn off your PC.

I select "Troubleshoot"->"Advanced options"->"System Image Recovery"

The Acer screen appears with "Preparing system Image Recovery" at the bottom. I sign into the Admin account when prompted to choose an account.

A window appears and scans for images. I choose the "Select a system image" option and then select the correct Windows 10 image.

Next, I select the only available option for "Select the date and time of system image to restore"

After this, there is a message which says "To restore this computer, Windows needs to format the drive that the Windows Recovery Environment is currently running on. To continue with the restore, shut down this computer and boot it from a Windows installation disc or a system repair disc and then try the restore again." At this point I have no way to continue.

Even if I plug in the USB Recovery Drive that we were using, I get the same message. I'm not sure what the problem is or how to get past it. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: My HP Desktop did this when I tried to upgrade from within Windows.  What I did to remedy was I changed the boot order to boot from USB, then installed the upgrade before Windows loaded.

Comment: I checked the boot order and I have USB HDD first, and Windows Boot Manager second. The only other option is the USB CDD, which is irrelevant because I'm not using a USB CDD drive @user2676140. There was no difference when I tried again

Comment: By image you mean a .wim image?  The lack of formatting makes this question hard to follow.

Comment: I believe it might be a .vhdx file